# Create a new variable using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a new variable in the dataset which is the first difference of a variable which already exists in the data set using dplyr mutate.

I am using the example data MaunaLoa

```
MaunaLoa = read.csv("http://course1.winona.edu/bdeppa/FIN%20335/Datasets/CO2%20Mauna%20Loa.csv")
```

The command dplyr works when I am just transforming the variable:

```
MaunaLoa <- dplyr::mutate(MaunaLoa, lnCO2 = log(CO2))
```

But not if I am attempting to create a new variable which is the first difference of an existing one:

```
MaunaLoa <- dplyr::mutate(MaunaLoa, CO2_diff = diff(CO2), na.omit=TRUE)
```

I get the following error message:

`CO2_diff must be size 468 or 1, not 467`

Is there anything I can specify not to make it crash?

Comment: The error message gives the clue: a vector of length n generates only (n-1) differences.  `dplyr` can't sensibly recycle this.  The solution is simple: provide one extra value.  Since the *first* row of the tibble has no predecessor, set the difference for this row to `NA`.  So: `MaunaLoa <- dplyr::mutate(MaunaLoa, CO2_diff = c(NA, diff(CO2)))`.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `lag` with the argument `default`. Explanation is given by Limey see comments:

```
library(dplyr)
MaunaLoa %>% 
    mutate(CO2_diff2 = (diff= CO2-lag(CO2,default=first(CO2))))
```

```
     Time Month  Year   CO2 lnCO2 CO2_diff2
   <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     1     1  1959  315.  5.75     0    
 2     2     2  1959  316.  5.76     0.890
 3     3     3  1959  316.  5.76     0.190
 4     4     4  1959  318.  5.76     1.06 
 5     5     5  1959  318.  5.76     0.570
 6     6     6  1959  318   5.76    -0.130
 7     7     7  1959  316.  5.76    -1.61 
 8     8     8  1959  315.  5.75    -1.74 
 9     9     9  1959  314.  5.75    -0.970
10    10    10  1959  313.  5.75    -0.5  
# ... with 458 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Function `diff()` returns a vector that will always be shorter than the list it processes. In this case where you are lagging by 1 (first difference) you need to fill "the first spot", probably with an NA or a 0. In my example I use an NA.

```
mutate(MaunaLoa, lnCO2 = log(CO2), 
   CO2_diff = c(NA, diff(CO2)), na.omit = TRUE)

# A tibble: 468 x 7
    Time Month  Year   CO2 lnCO2 CO2_diff na.omit
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <lgl>  
 1     1     1  1959  315.  5.75   NA     TRUE   
 2     2     2  1959  316.  5.76    0.890 TRUE   
 3     3     3  1959  316.  5.76    0.190 TRUE   
 4     4     4  1959  318.  5.76    1.06  TRUE   
 5     5     5  1959  318.  5.76    0.570 TRUE   
 6     6     6  1959  318   5.76   -0.130 TRUE   
 7     7     7  1959  316.  5.76   -1.61  TRUE   
 8     8     8  1959  315.  5.75   -1.74  TRUE   
 9     9     9  1959  314.  5.75   -0.970 TRUE   
10    10    10  1959  313.  5.75   -0.5   TRUE   
# ... with 458 more rows
```